# the generated module is rendered multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to fetch some movies from a JSON file and then use handlebars to render it on my page. Unfortunately, the data get rendered multiple times. Does anyone know what approach I should try to fix this?

The middleware:

```
  const FavoriteMoviesArray = async (req, res, next) => {
      const generatedHTMLArrayFavorites = await movieContainerCreator.getMovieHTMLArrayFavorites();
      res.locals.generatedHTMLArrayFavorites = generatedHTMLArrayFavorites;
     
     
      if (!req.session.generatedHTMLArrayFavorites) {
        const generatedHTMLArrayFavorites = res.locals.generatedHTMLArrayFavorites;
        req.session.generatedHTMLArrayFavorites = generatedHTMLArrayFavorites;
      }
  
      next();

  };
```

The route:

```
  app.get("/Favorite.html", redirectLogin, FavoriteMoviesArray, async function (req, res) {
    try {
  
      const favoritesHTMLArray = req.session.generatedHTMLArrayFavorites;

      res.render("Favorite", { generatedHTMLArrayFavorites: favoritesHTMLArray });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
  });
```

The handlebars snippet:

```
    {{#each generatedHTMLArray}}
      {{{this}}}
    {{/each}}
```

I tried to assign it to a session and, if it is present, then not to assign it again; but no luck.

Comment: What is `generatedHTMLArrayFavorites`? Is it an array of strings?

Comment: yes is an array of strings which has the html code inside

Comment: It's hard to determine what your issue is from the code you have provided. The `FavoriteMoviesArray` middleware seems to me to be a bad design choice, but I don't think it is the cause of your immediate problem. I suspect the issue has to do with `getMovieHTMLArrayFavorites`; would you be able to share what is returned by that function?